# Rails find_or_initialize_by without db query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

Is there any rails method that does the same as `find_or_initialize_by`, but **without a database query**?

The problem is:

**1.) It can lead to something like an "n+1" query.**

For example I have a `Question` model that `has_many :translations` connecting it to the `Translation` model which has the attributes (columns) `language` and `value`. When editing a question I have a nested form for `:translations`, but first I need to build the missing languages in the controller. If I do

```
%w(en hu fr de it).each do |lng|
  @question.translations.find_or_initialize_by(language: lng)
end
```

it will run a query for every five languages, even if I have eager loaded `:translations`.

**2.) It doesn't find non-persisted elements** (exactly because of querying in the database).

So if in the previous form someone fills only 'en' translation of `@question`, submits the form, but some validation fails, the form gets re-rendered with error messages, there are two possibilities: either I do *not* run the `find_or_initialize_by` for each languages (in this case ***only*** the 'en' field will be displayed), or I *run* it (and 'en' field will be ***duplicated*** - the first will contain the submitted but not persisted `value`, the second will be empty)

What I use is the following (inside `each`'s block):

```
@question.translations.select{ |t| t.language == lng }.first ||
    @question.translations.build(language: lng)
```

which works just fine but I think it is not DRY enough (as it duplicates `@question.translations`, `language` and `lng`), and I really hope there is some **"rails way"** to do this.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: A method using anything like "find" related will be doing a query however what is your end goal? To prefill the form with the fields for those translations? If so you can do that with `accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations` and building the `@question.translations` only in the "new" action in your controller. Let me know if that was what you are asking and I will elaborate it an answer

Comment: @JoseCastellanos imagine a `form_for @question` that has some own fields (title, default_language...), and then `fields_for :translations` (with all it needs: `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, params whitelisted...). The translations fields consist of a `hidden_field` for `language` identified by a flag and a `text_field` for `value`. The goal is that **the user sees all possible languages** (once) even if there is no trasnlation for that language (and I reject `:translation` if value is blank). Is that well explained?